# double quotes in view name

Tags: sqlite, escaping, double-quotes, sqlitemanager

I'm trying to create a view in sqlite that contains double quotes (I'm using the SQlite Manager Addon in Firefox). According to the escape rules (doubling double quotes) the following statement should work

```
CREATE VIEW "Name with ""quotes""" AS SELECT columnname FROM tablename
```

However it doesn't and gives me the following error message when I try to look at it.

[image: Error Message when using the SQL command schown above]

Answer (score 0):

This command is correct.

The poblem is caused by SQLite Manager, which does not apply the quoting rules correctly. Please [report](https://github.com/lazierthanthou/sqlite-manager/issues) this bug.